# Style li tag with Sass doesnt work (hover effect for li tag)

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following HTML code:

```
<button class='drpDwnRp'>Select...<span class='caret'></span></button> 
<ul class='dropdown-menu'> 
    <li><a><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>SELECT All</a></li> 
    <li><a><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>DELETE All</a></li> 
    <li class='divider'></li> 
    <li><a>LIST here</li> 
</ul>
```

Can someone please let me know how to style with Sass?

I tried the following and it didn't work. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
.drpDwnRp{
    @extend .drpDwn;
    color: white;
    text-align:left;
    background-color: red;

    .caret {
        margin-left:169px;
        color:black;
    }

    li:hover {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

Styling for `.drpDwnRp` and `.caret` works.

Comment: @cocoa-sorry for the typo. updated the post.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. `li` is not a child of `.drpDwnRp`, so `li:hover` should not be nested inside that class, but `.dropdown-menu` instead
2. You are missing `</a>` on the last `li`

```css
.drpDwnRp {
    @extend .drpDwn;
    color: white;
    text-align:left;
    background-color: blue;
}
.drpDwnRp .caret {
    margin-left:169px;
    color:black;
}
.dropdown-menu li:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<button class='drpDwnRp'>Select...
    <span class='caret'></span>
</button>
<ul class='dropdown-menu'>
    <li>
        <a><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>SELECT All</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>DELETE All</a>
    </li>
    <li class='divider'></li>
    <li><a>LIST here</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: how does it not work? I added a code snippet with my suggested edits.

Answer (score 1):

The `<li>` element is outside of `.drpDwnRp`, that's why your code fails. You should do this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    li:hover {
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

That's how your `<li>` will be formatted as you want. Have fun!